# Font style in DataRow ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

I was trying to change the font size on specific row cell depends on what length the string is by using `DataRow`, using `DataGridView` I get an error, same with the `DataGrid`. How can I manipulate the cell in every row using `DataRow`?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Command Here")) 
{
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow asd in dt.Rows)
    {
         if (asd[4].ToString().Length >= 45)
         {
             asd[4] = "test";
         }
    }
}
```

I know using `=` is setting a new value for that column cell, but I was trying to manipulate its style.

Comment: Do you mean you want to modify DataRow to add a style for the DataGridView or you want to add a new column for the datarow? Datarow is a data type not the CSS style or else

Comment: I want to modify DataRow to add a style, to add style should I really use `DataGridView`?

Comment: DataRow doesn't contain the style property. As I said before, it's just a data type. The style should be set inside the DataGridView or gradview or else. Which other view or web control which used the Datarow as the database. So you could add the style as the new datatype inside the datatable and then inside the datagridview you could read it.